# PHP arrays for looping on memory usage

Tags: php, arrays

If I have array like this :

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => NO
        [1] => SIZE TCT
        [2] => INPUT_LOT
        [3] => NET
        [4] => GROSS
        [5] => LENGTH
        [6] => CONT
        [7] => SEAL
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 0.720*151.8
        [2] => DNA07X1A513041608A
        [3] => 4120
        [4] => 4160
        [5] => 4896
        [6] => 
        [7] => 
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2
        [1] => 0.720*151.8
        [2] => DNA07X1A513041607A
        [3] => 4220
        [4] => 4260
        [5] => 5056
        [6] => 
        [7] => 
    )
```

)

I want to convert them into row by row in html table;
My question is:

1. What type of array like this ?  Is that array associative ?
2. Which is the best way to iterate them based memory usage, foreach, for loop, while or what ?

I really appreciated for the help.
Thanks

Comment: It's just a two dimensional array with numerical enumerated 0-based keys. And you probably want to use just 2 simple foreach loops.

Comment: explain  `memory usage` as you said ? you need only one foreach/for loop.

Comment: Looping itself doesn't significantly affect memory usage in any way; it's what you do inside that loop which may make a difference

Comment: I commonly use for then foreach inside for

Answer (score 2):

> ***What type of array like this ? Is that array associative ?***

No, it's a [two dimensional array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

---

> ***Which is the best way to iterate them based memory usage, foreach, for
>   loop, while or what ?***

In such a simple array, you shouldn't be concerned about memory usage, but the `for` loop **consumes less memory** than `foreach`, because `foreach` uses an internal copy of the array.

> As foreach relies on the internal array pointer in PHP 5, changing it
>   within the loop may lead to unexpected behavior.
>   In PHP 7, foreach does not use the internal array pointer.
>   http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 0):

This is a 2D array and the best way to iterate it using foreach loop.

Comment: I commonly use for then foreach inside for

Comment: You can also use for loop for same it will take less memory than foreach...because foreach loop create a internal copy of an array.

Comment: Can you give me an eample, please ?